# What's the best way to count the results of a custom search

Tags: catalogsearch

I use this code :

```
$queryText = 'test';
$query = Mage::helper('catalogSearch')->getQuery();
$query->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$query->setQueryText(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->setQueryText($queryText));

$collection = $query->getSearchCollection();
$collection->addSearchFilter(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getQueryText());
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes());
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
```

to make a custom search collection. 
I don't want to have a full collection, but only to count the number of results.

What's the best way to make this ? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
$count = $collection->getSize();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure what's the better way to customize the query Filter and the select options to use the minimum required to do it efficiently...

Comment: It seams you are doing it right. Maybe you can lose the `$collection->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes());` if you need only the size of the collection.